# ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am getting below error while i run ionic project:
I'm getting an error when building an Ionic 3 app 1

```
[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master anand$ ionic cordova run android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
/Users/anand/projects/Ionic/ShoppingCart/ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13
      throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
      ^

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.3
    at module.exports (/Users/anand/projects/Ionic/ShoppingCart/ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anand/projects/Ionic/ShoppingCart/ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anand/projects/Ionic/ShoppingCart/ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/core/bundle-components.js:6:16)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

        ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master anand$ ionic cordova platform rm ios

> cordova platform remove ios --save
>       Removing platform ios from config.xml file...
>   ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master anand$ ionic cordova run android
>   ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
>       /Users/anand/projects/Ionic/ShoppingCart/ionic3-firebase-shopping-cart-master/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13
>             throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());

Comment: For me remove node_modules folder and then run `npm install` works.

Answer (score 14):

After a long try I resolved this with below command:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

And it worked.

**Also if not working then** try to downgrade the app-script dependency in package.json as below:

From

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4"
```

to

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3"
```

Hope it will help someone

Comment: Also please check your dependencies in package.json file. It generally comes because of dependencies mismatch.

Answer (score 9):

Delete the entire `node_modules` folder in your project and then run this command :

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

It will work just fine.

Comment: Just delete `node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts` and execute the command

Answer (score 1):

**Got the same problem (node v10.3.0, ionic 3.13.0). This worked :**

Delete package-lock.json,

Delete node_modules folder,

Run npm install again.

Answer (score 1):

some files was deleted or hidden

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was the latest app-scripts version. I downgraded by changing

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4"
```

in package.json to

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3"
```

and running

```
npm install
```