# Build failed with Angular AOT

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build an Ionic project with `ionic cordova build android --prod tag`

When I try with dev or normal build, it works. But with *prod* it gives an error.

Here is my **packages.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "chimera",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "0.12.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "3.0.1",
    "angular2-masonry": "0.4.0",
    "call-number": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.13.1",
    "cordova-android": "6.4.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.13.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.7",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-marquee": "0.4.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "ng2-twitter": "0.3.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.5.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-sources": "1.3.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.2",
    "@types/xml2js": "0.4.3",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly."
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {
        "ADMOB_APP_ID": "ca-app-pub-2899054860592317~3367233553"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "call-number": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my **env file:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.0.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 6.4.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.3 Build version 10G8
```

I have no idea what it's doing.

Got this **error:**

```
[14:19:12]  typescript error 
            Error during template compile of 'BrowserXhr' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 
            'makeDecorator' was called in 'Injectable' 'Injectable' references 'Injectable' 'Injectable' references 
            'Injectable' 'Injectable' references 'Injectable' 'Injectable' calls 'makeDecorator'. 

[14:19:12]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[14:19:12]  Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above 
Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at /Users/wasiq/Desktop/development/fantaproapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (/Users/wasiq/Desktop/development/fantaproapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/wasiq/Desktop/development/fantaproapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/wasiq/Desktop/development/fantaproapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
```

Already tried a few things like commenting a few code lines, but I don't get which file is causing that error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's something to do with forRoot() your module import. Try adding ".forRoot() as show: @NgModule({
    imports: [
        YourModule.forRoot(),
    ],
   ...
}

Comment: Or perhaps or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792228/error-an-error-occurred-while-running-subprocess-ionic-app-scripts

Comment: @RobinWebb i try both sorry didnt work. just drive me nuts from last 6 hours noting works

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue
try (re)installing  @ionic/app-scripts@latest

```
npm --save install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

sometimes npm sub modules are not correctly saved in node modules.

Comment: Already tried that remove it from node module and install it again or update it again but same error

Comment: try deleting the whole node modules and installing everything again. Also this could be caused by miss match between the npm package versions in you package.json. Those warnings you get seem a bit odd to me, look for example package.json with compatible versions.

Comment: its not working can you please suggest something else

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1516
This might be related, also try updating the versions in your package json, it seems they are not compatible. Here is my package.json is is missing some of your dependencies but I don't get your error. 
https://pastebin.com/k60kXtTD.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks let me check